# Bazel Build Permission denied

Tags: c++, gcc, build, bazel, permission-denied

Recently, I'm trying to learn the NVidia Isaac which is built by Bazel.

While I was following the document here:

https://docs.nvidia.com/isaac/isaac/doc/getting_started.html#running-an-application

I encountered an error kept saying the cpp files Bazel need to build is "Permission denied".
The error message looks like below:

```
Use --sandbox_debug to see verbose messages from the sandbox
gcc: error: engine/alice/components/Subprocess.cpp: Permission denied
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
ERROR: /home/acas/HDD/CatDog/Isaak/engine/alice/BUILD:23:1: Couldn't build file engine/alice/_objs/impl/ReplayBridge.o: C++ compilation of rule '//engine/alice:impl' faed (Exit 1) crosstool_wrapper_driver_is_not_gcc_host.py failed: error executing command external/toolchain/crosstool/scripts/crosstool_wrapper_driver_is_not_gcc_host.pyD_DEFAULT_SOURCE -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -fstack-protector -Wall -Werror -B/usr/bin -Wunused-but-set-parameter ... (remaining 183 argument(s) skipped)

Use --sandbox_debug to see verbose messages from the sandbox
gcc: error: engine/alice/components/ReplayBridge.cpp: Permission denied
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
ERROR: /home/acas/HDD/CatDog/Isaak/engine/gems/image/BUILD:42:1: Couldn't build file engine/gems/image/_objs/cuda_conversions/yuv2rgb.cu.o: error while parsing .d file:root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/6ab44b9a455585caa8f9f5f55ddd002b/execroot/com_nvidia_isaac/bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/engine/gems/image/_objs/cuda_conversions/yuv2rgb.cu.d (No ch file or directory)
gcc: error: engine/gems/image/cuda/yuv2rgb.cu.cpp: Permission denied
gcc: warning: '-x c++' after last input file has no effect
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
Target //apps/samples/stereo_dummy:stereo_dummy failed to build
Use --verbose_failures to see the command lines of failed build steps.
INFO: Elapsed time: 6.627s, Critical Path: 0.62s, Remote (0.00% of the time): [queue: 0.00%, setup: 0.00%, process: 0.00%]
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
```

And so much the same "Permission denied" error.

I've tried root, sudo, but none of that works.

Is anyone has the same Bazel problem (I think this problem is not about NVidia Isaac but Bazel)?

Comment: Is your driver (HD) mounted with "rw" permissions? (Im assuming your are on a linux/unix SO, once you have mentioned that you have tried root, sudo)

Comment: @Amadeus thanks for the prompt reply. Yes I use ubuntu 18.04.1, and the output of "mount" is "/dev/sdb1 on /home/acas/HDD type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,data=ordered,x-gvfs-show)". Therefore, I think I have the rw permission.

Comment: The next natural step is to verify the permissions of your directory/files tree. Look to see if you have permissions to write and execute on directories

Comment: @Amadeus Yes I do have the permission, I just make & delete a test.cpp in the path under the same folder with "engine/alice/components/ReplayBridge.cpp". The permission problem occurred when I use bazel to build those cpp files.

Comment: I'm hitting that with a custom bazel rule that I suspect is lacking these intra macro dependencies being passed to subsequent targets that get generated and built in the macro. ie. `def outerMacro() ...   innerMacroA ()... innerMacroB( deps=["targets_from_A"] )`, I found the deps stuff is absent, and I'll be experimenting to see if it addresses the access problem.

Comment: Move to a directory where you are allowed to write/Read. And also try with sudo commands  'sudo chown -R "$USER:" /path/to/the/directory'
Set read/write/execute permission

'chmod -R 700 /path/to/the/directory'